# Could not find version error during install Imblearn in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, scikit-learn, imblearn

I am trying to install Imblearn for doing SMOTE in python. I have been trying to install imblearn package for sometime. But I am constantly getting errors. The following are the commands that I have tried,

```
pip install imblearn

pip install git+https://github.com/fmfn/UnbalancedDataset
```

And following is the error that I am getting,

```
Collecting imblearn
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/81/a7/4179e6ebfd654bd0eac0b9c06125b8b4c96a9d0a8ff9e9507eb2a26d2d7e/imblearn-0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting imbalanced-learn (from imblearn)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e0/87/39a4cecebc7fb9ddb433fe8bc7f76379b4918a0ade91f8a1423dc25c7ddc/imbalanced-learn-0.5.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11 in 
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.17 in 
Collecting scikit-learn>=0.21 (from imbalanced-learn->imblearn)
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement scikit-learn>=0.21 (from imbalanced-learn->imblearn) (from versions: 0.9, 0.10, 0.11, 0.12, 0.12.1, 0.13, 0.13.1, 0.14, 0.14.1, 0.15.0b1, 0.15.0b2, 0.15.0, 0.15.1, 0.15.2, 0.16b1, 0.16.0, 0.16.1, 0.17b1, 0.17, 0.17.1, 0.18rc2, 0.18, 0.18.1, 0.18.2, 0.19b2, 0.19.0, 0.19.1, 0.19.2, 0.20rc1, 0.20.0, 0.20.1, 0.20.2, 0.20.3, 0.21rc2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for scikit-learn>=0.21 (from imbalanced-learn->imblearn)
```

Because of this I am not able to proceed my modeling part as my data is heavily imbalanced. Can anybody please help me in installing this package? if not, what are the alternate ways to do SMOTE in python ?

Comment: Looks like there is a some version incompatibilty. The same command works for pip3 though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scikit-learn 0.20 was the last version to support Python2.7. Scikit-learn 0.21 and later require Python 3.5 or newer.

Refer to the following link:

> https://pypi.org/project/scikit-learn/0.21.0/

I would recommend using Python3

Answer (score 0):

the pip install command has changed. It is as below

```
https://pypi.org/project/scikit-learn/0.21.0/
```

Comment: my bad i copied the wrong link i have now corrected it